# Sifr text not appearing

Tags: sifr

This is the website I'm working on: http://ruderic.com.ar/demos/simplestyle/index.html

The problem is that the text that's supposed to be converted does not appear at all in Firefox. In IE8, it's not converted.

I think I followed the How-To correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but I think you might perfer CuFon - I find it much simpler and more effective.

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/